# Duplicate activity launched from notification

Tags: android

I display my notification like this .

```
// Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,homeIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MATCHES_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_avengers)
        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("Title"))
        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("Body"))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.user_avatar))
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(remoteMessage.getData().get("Body")));

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
notificationManager.notify(10, mBuilder.build());
```

But no matter what I do , the flags from the homeactivity which is my root dont seem to work. My HomeActivity is pushed on to whereever the user is in my Application .

I want the current copy of the homeactivity to come to the top and the rest should be destroyed.

Comment: Is your onNewIntent called or not?

Comment: No it is not. I have an entire new root activity on top of where i am at a given moment :(